# KMZ Quality: Desktop vs Plugin

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, kml, google-earth, kmz

Is there a reason why the quality of KMZ images, when added to a website using the Google Earth Plugin, drop in quality (it appears blurry) compared to when the same KMZ is seen through Google Earth Desktop?

Comment: This should be asked in two separate questions (since there are two questions in your question). This should also _not_ be a request for tips since that would lead to "list"-type answers, which is not what this site is good for. (But otherwise, good questions; I'd like to hear the answers myself.)

Comment: Rie Mino - Please take Micheal Todd's advice and separate the questions to get good defined answers.